# PayPal Integration in Indian currency checkout

Tags: php, paypal

Hi i am new for PayPal integrate with PHP. i am confuse for Indian currency (INR)
can i checkout by Indian currency ...

Comment: advance thanks .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal doesn't support Indian currency so far. My best guess would be to be use 'USD' as the currency. PayPal will itself convert it to 'INR' and send it to your bank account.

You cannot maintain an INR balance on PayPal account due to some local regulations, instead your balance is automatically swept to your local bank account.

Your customers will pay in USD, you'll receive USD, PayPal will convert USD to INR and send to your bank account.

(Also, Stack Overflow isn't the right place to ask this.)